# Problems getting a random element from ArrayCollection in Symfony 2

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

Anyone can help me? I'm getting this error trying to load DataFixtures:

```
Notice: Undefined index:  in path/DataFixtures/ORM/Fixture.php
```

Here's my simple code... I can't see why is failing, because i did it before with another fixture and it worked

```
$things = $manager->getRepository('namespaceBundle:Entity')->findByProperty($property->getId());
$thing = $things[array_rand($things)];
```

I'm just trying to get a random object from ArrayCollection `$things`

I need some help, i'm stucked... and i'm sure it's an stupid mistake, but i can't see it!

Thanks!

Comment: did you check what `array_rand` returns?

Comment: I don't know what the f*** i'm doing wrong.... How can I check what it's returning?i'm just trying to load fixtures in the DB and returns this warning: `array_rand() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`

Comment: Well, so you already know what's wrong. `$things` is an object, not an array. You need to pass an array to use array functions.

Answer (score 15):

Simplest would be

```
$thing = $things->get(array_rand($things->toArray()));
```

Comment: I really don't know why it didn't worked, because the sentence is correct and I used it before in another entity... weird...